# Как получить время затраченное на тест Selenium Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, selenium

Написал тест, который открывает страницу и ждет пока данные будут загружены, время засекаю сразу после нажатия на кнопку, до того момента, пока не будут загружены все данные

```
ChangeMethodPaymentButton.Click();
stopwatch.Start();
_browser.WaitForElement(By.CssSelector("#method-..."));
stopwatch.Stop();
TimeSpan ts = stopwatch.Elapsed;
string elapsedTime = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}.{3:00}",
ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds,
ts.Milliseconds / 10);
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(elapsedTime);
```

Время засекаю с помощью *Stopwatch* и вывожу его с помощью `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(elapsedTime);`

но этот способо работает только при дебаге,каким способом можно вывести время когда тест запускается не в режиме дебага ?

P.S.Конечно я могу записывать это время в файл, но по-моему это "велосипед", хотелось бы использовать какой-то цивилизованный способ.